# Cannot Add New Record When a Control on the Form is Bound to an SQL Bit Column

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a form in a VB.Net Windows form app with one control bound to a Bit column in an SQL table. The form also contains a Binding Navigator (along with other controls bound to the same table).
When I click the Add New button on the Binding Navigator, the record count showing on the Binding Navigator increments by one, but it will not allow me to navigate to the new record.
If I remove the data binding to this column and leave all the other data bindings in tact, the Add New button works as expected.
I have checked the bit column in the SQL table to ensure it does not allow Nulls and the default value is set to (0).
How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Larry. Questions without any code are generally poorly-received. Please edit your post with some relevant code and we can help you better.

Comment: Sorry for not including the code. To resolve this issue, I changed the Add New Item property of the Binding Navigator to "none" and in the BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click event I programmatically added a new record and set the bit column value to "false". I guess the default value of (0) in the SQL table was not carrying through.